# How to know if the Done button was clicked Action Mode

Tags: android, android-actionmode

I'm implementing a actionmode is'm doubts as whether the done button was clicked, 
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean just when done is clicked, and not when other ways of leaving the actionmode is used?  Or when the action mode is closed no matter what way?

Comment: I need to know when the done is clicked, to call my method onSave(), or is not possible? or it´s not correct mode?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:`onActionItemClicked(ActionMode, MenuItem)`

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionMode.Callback.html)

Comment: but and the id for DONE?

Comment: `int doneButtonId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android");`

Comment: WARNING: the above is an inflexible solution and it is essentially accessing a private API. If Google ever changes the name of action_mode_close_button, this will cease to work.

Comment: For those using Holoeverywhere library, use the int value: org.holoeverywhere.R.id.action_mode_close_button as the id to get reference to the DONE viewResource. 

Note: do this only when getSystem().getIdentifier("action_mode_close_button", "id", "android") returns 0;

Comment: I don't get a call to my `onActionItemClicked` when I press done in the API 21 emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this approach - set a boolean flag when any action item is clicked (in onActionItemClicked). Then in callback's onDestroyActionMode I check this flag and is it is not set then the done button was tapped. It assumes that you finish action mode in onActionItemClicked.

Answer (score 0):

if the Done button was clicked 。

this method onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {}  will  call  back .

so you can  call your method onSave().

if  you  can't find  this  method, you  can  gooogle  find  which  interface you

need  implements.